# Oracle, how to insert LONG RAW (a hex string is much longer than 32767) into BLOB in a query

Tags: database, oracle, sql-insert

for the hex strings <= 32767 I do:

```
DECLARE buf RAW(32767);
BEGIN
buf := hextoraw('3082560E3082488E1B02....');
INSERT INTO FINGERPRINT VALUES ('bff17a2c-49b7-4d6c-9c4e-56cb1d35c8c8', '00003', 2, buf, NULL);
END;
```

How to do the same way but if a string is longer than 32767? I tried to use LONG RAW instead of RAW(32767) but getting an error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing asktom:

> In Oracle8i, releases 8.0 and up, you should not be using LONG RAW. Both LONG and LONG RAW are only provided for backwards compatibility -- they are deprecated datatypes.
> You should be using blob

If it still produces error try working with:

- dbms_lob.createtemporary

and then

- dbms_lob.append